# What do I need to implement to run Max on a List<class>?

Tags: c#, linq

Lets say I have a classes A and B:

```
class A
{
    public B myValue;
}

class B
{
}
```

I have a `List<A> myList` and I want to be able to call:

`var maxValue = myList.Max(a => a.myValue);`

What do I need to change in `B` to be able to run `.Max()`?

Comment: Is this a hypothetical question, or does the compiler perhaps give you any hints on what you should do? Or perhaps you get a useful runtime exception?

Comment: @SaeedAmiri Because you can't accept answers if the question is closed, iirc

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your myValue should be of type [`IComparable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4d7sx9hd.aspx), actually you should implement this interface for your specific type.

Comment: @ReedCopsey Not directly, but still, look at MSDN: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb534962.aspx, especially remarks. I know they messed up there, but it mentions IComparable.

Comment: @ReedCopsey, I didn't see your comment, but I guess that you mentioned should implement IComparable<T>, and others said that why my answer is correct. But I agree that IComparable<T> is less confusing for linq style, so I updated my answer by link to IComparable<T>, to reflect this possible suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

As per [`Enumerable.Max<TSource>()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb347632%28v=vs.90%29.aspx):

> If type `TSource` implements `IComparable<T>`, this method uses that implementation to compare values. Otherwise, if type `TSource` implements `IComparable`, that implementation is used to compare values.

Comment: Sorry, my example was incorrect.